# How to get the list elements that are not into another list C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to know how to get the elements that are not into another list of the same type.

Example

```
List<Person> list1;
List<Person> list2;

list1[0] = "A"
list1[1] = "B"
list1[2] = "C"
list1[3] = "D"

list2[0] = "C"
list2[1] = "D"
```

I want a new list with the elements A and B

I was trying to do this but it's not working.

```
var newList =list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: Yes, this should be working if you are using the System.Linq namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Note that `Person` is likely not a value type, but a reference type.  Therefore, `Except` will not compare values, but rather references.  If you want to apply the "Except" logic by a property of the instances (let's say "Name"), then use something like this:

```
string[] valuesToExclude = list1.Select(person => person.Name).ToArray();
var newList = list2.Where(person => !valuesToExclude.Contains(person.Name)).ToList();
```

2) You could alternatively pass an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` to `Except`:

```
public class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

It's the second parameter, as in:

```
var newList = list2.Except(list1, new PersonComparer()).ToList();
```

3) Lastly, it's worth noting that if `Person` were a `struct` (value type), then your code would work as-is, **assuming** that all the properties matched for the instances you are excepting.  For example:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

List<Person> list1 = new List<Person> 
{ 
    new Person { Name = "A" }, 
    new Person { Name = "B" },  
};
List<Person> list2 = new List<Person> 
{
    new Person { Name = "A" }, 
};
var newList = list1.Except(list2).ToList(); 
   // "B" only
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is most likely not working because it's doing reference comparisons, meaning if `A` and `B` are `Person` objects and have the same values for every property `A != B` is true and `A == B` is false. Now if I had;

```
Person A = new Person();
Person B = A;

A == B // this is true now, that's the comparison Except is doing
```

So, you probably want to define a custom equality comparer. You can do that like so;

```
   class PersonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
    {
        public bool Equals(Person lhs, Person rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Name == rhs.Name;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Person p)
        {
            return p.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then call Except like so;

```
 var diff =  list1.Except(list2, new PersonEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: @jimtollan can you expand? Do mean you think there's a problem with my code or is it just not the approach you're familiar with?

Comment: evan - it's a nice take on the comparer and probably one that would have whooshed over my head, had i sat down to think about it... very nice and a +1 for your efforts...